# New Android Studio Update

Tags: android, android-studio

I just updated my Android studio to version 2.2.2. My emulator worked perfectly prior the update, and now the emulator won't even start after the update. Thank you all so much in advance!

Also, I have already installed Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator in my SDK Manager.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAyPn.png)

Comment: And what exactly is your question? How to roll back to 2.2.1? How to set up an Emulator? How to fix a crashed Emulator? I can't see anything here that is a question for a develop forum.

Comment: Sorry for not specifying the question. I would like to know how I could fix the error that is showing. More specifically, what should I do in order to run the emulator again.

Comment: I see - sorry didn't recognize that screenshot at first. Well looks like a HAXM problem. Have you tried uninstalling and fresh reinstalling the haxm driver? Have you tried a new Emulator? Setting up a new one is not a big deal or do you have tons of configurations stored on your emulator? My first idea would be a reroll of the driver.

Comment: I've tried reinstalling the haxm driver as well as setting up a new emulator. no luck with both

Comment: when on a x64 cpu (what i think is the case these days) - have you tried creating an x86_64 emulator?
Or do you need an x86 explicitly?

Comment: i tried creating an x86_64 emulator, still dosent work

Comment: hmmm. sorry I am out then. No more ideas. I hope, someone else comes up with new ideas. Good luck!